BitBucket API - GET lines added & lines deleted per commit
Is there any API available in Bitbucket to get No of Lines added / Deleted for particular Commit
found below API for return that info but not sure about path because in commits API response path is not available:
API to Get diff stats summary between revisions:
 http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/{commitId}/diff-stats-summary/{path}

I am not sure from where we get get path, I checked commits API but its not returing path in response
http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits

